# Unit testing Spring MVC app with tests based on actual View DOM

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, spring-mvc

We have a Spring MVC webapp, and we're currently able to unit test the controllers with `MockHttpServletRequest` objects.

Our tests look similar to:

```
request = new MockHttpServletRequest(_mockServletContext, "PUT", "/createNewUser.action");
request.setParameter("username", "bob123");
response = new MockHttpServletResponse();
userController.createNewUser(request, response);
// Ensure the user was created, etc.
```

Then, we query the underlying database (and other controllers) to ensure that things worked properly.

However, this **does not** test the actual JSP pages that we're shipping. Just the fair-weather mocked request.

What we would *like* to accomplish, is being able to mock the entire process from the perspective of an actual user viewing the page in a browser, like:

```
request = new MockHttpServletRequest(_mockServletContext, "GET", "/newUser.html");
response = new MockHttpServletResponse();
userController.newUser(request, response);
//Pseudo-code!
DOM thePage = SomeBuilder.fromResponse(response);
thePage.getTextField("usernameField").setText("bob123");
thePage.getButton("submitUserButton").click();
// Then, we test the same assertions
...
```

This helps us establish unit tests based on the view as the client will actually see it, and would involve ensuring that the proper HTML components exist, and the Javascript backing the button click is also sending the proper parameters to the server/controller, in the event it someday requires a user's first name, for example. **Or,** in the case there is a typo and the HTML form actually sends the parameter "userUsername" instead of "username". We'd like to remove the manual testing requirement in this case, as there are different code paths/form layouts depending on the role of the currently-authenticated user.

Are there Java/Spring MVC based unit testing frameworks to accomplish this task? Or other code patterns that would provide similar reliability?

Comment: No. You will need to do some integration testing with a framework like `Selenium`.

Comment: Thanks @SotiriosDelimanolis - that's what we ended up using, to much success.